# Can't make unit testing works in xamarin studio

Tags: nunit, monodevelop

I'm trying to follow this tutorials:

www.codeproject.com/Articles/34161/Setup-a-Test-Project-with-NUnit-and-MonoDevelop

but when i click "Run tests", they are gray and no results showed:

screenshot:
http://img585.imageshack.us/img585/8003/111vuq.png

how can I make them work ?

Comment: No one ? Somebody save me =))

Comment: I've tested this project with NUnit gui, and it works, but within xamarin -> not. The same issue. Here is screenshot of nunit gui: http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/1346/221w.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution. My windows's firewall was blocking connections, after adding some rules, all started working. That's all +)